# Chrome: Go to URL via console

Tags: google-chrome

A long time ago, I was reading that there is a way to go to a specific URL via the Chrome Console. I am wondering if anyone knows the command that would do so?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.document.location = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Comment: You're welcome. I think you can use Chrome Console the same way you use any JavaScript interpreter. So, next time you can just look for JavaScript commands if you want to do something at Chrome Console. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the url needs to include the http(s):// part.

Comment: This is actually useful now for messing with Electron apps.